# Implementing CASL with React and Redux

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, casl

I will be referencing this article https://medium.com/dailyjs/managing-user-permissions-in-your-react-app-a93a94ff9b40

I will be implementing role based authentication for certain routes in my react application and came across CASL. I see they have a react implementation but theres a certain area which confuses me. Please see the below code and I will explain after.

```
import { AbilityBuilder } from 'casl'

function subjectName(item) { 
if (!item || typeof item === 'string') {
    return item  
    }  
return item.__type
}
export default AbilityBuilder.define({ subjectName }, can => {
    can(['read', 'create'], 'Todo') 
    can(['update', 'delete'], 'Todo', { assignee: 'me' })
});
```

The area from above which confuses me is the 'Todo' in the export default function  can(['read', 'create'], 'Todo') 
What is this 'Todo'? In the article he describes it as such, ***"The second argument is object type, in our case Todo, for which this rule is applicable."***  Where does he get this object type, from `subjectName`?

I have looked around and also found an example using a logged in user via redux (closer to my hopeful implementation) and found this https://github.com/stalniy/casl/issues/148

What I want to have implemented: 
My application is for college and is a a remake of a grants website for researchers at university level. (I.E researchers can see available grants, apply to them, etc.) and I will have admins who can login to this same application and be able to upload grants and accept/reject researchers grant applications. Therefore I need to be able to have routes protected from certain roles of user.

How I hope it will work:
User logs in. 
If researcher -> allow them to see all grants, and apply to them, also view their status
if admin -> see grants applications and accept/reject them 
Essentially hide routes for both people. (admin cant apply for grant, researcher cant accept applications etc.)

Any information on how to implement this in react would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can read comments in https://github.com/stalniy/casl/issues/135 to understand what Todo is. In short, this is an entity name on which you want to define access. `subjectName` is a function which can extract entity name from entity instance when checking permissions using `ability.can(...)`